# Flash getter method is not able to return a 2D Array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, multidimensional-array

As the title says. I tried it with a String or a normal Array and it works. But when I try to pass on my 2D Array my class won't get anything. We're talking about an Array 16 width and about 50 in length.

In my XMLLoader.as class I have this:

```
function getConvoArray():Array
    {
        trace("convoArray send");
        return convoArray;
    }
```

And in my DialogueGenerator.as class I have this:

```
xmlLoader = new XMLLoader("ConvoLines.xml");
convoArray = xmlLoader.getConvoArray();
```

I've checked if the variable convoArray is filled in the XMLLoader.as class by tracing it in a for loop; it works perfectly. But then, when I try to pass it on to the DialogueGenerator.as class it seems to be empty. I cannot excess anything and Flash doesn't give me an error or a warning.

I simply have my Array in DialogueGenerator declared as this:

```
public var convoArray:Array;
```

But I tried different ways of declaring it.

Is there a solution for this? A workaround?

Comment: You're suffering from a typical problem for beginners. [`XMLLoader`](https://greensock.com/asdocs/com/greensock/loading/XMLLoader.html) loads data *asynchronously*, meaning the data is not immediately available as you have here. You need to attach an event listener to it and wait for the data to load before you attempt to interact with it.

Comment: @Marty Thank you so much for your quick reply! Can you give me some hints to any specific tutorial I should look for on adding an event which handles XML loading completion?

Comment: [The second code example here](https://greensock.com/asdocs/com/greensock/loading/XMLLoader.html) has a demonstration of how to do it :-)

Comment: Thanks, you're my savior. I had no clue that asynchronously data loading was a thing

Answer (score 0):

For loading xml I use something like this....

```
var fileName:String = "ConvoLines.xml";
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoaderComplete);
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, LoaderError);
loader.load(new URLRequest(fileName + "?rnd=" + Math.random())); 
// we affix rand to prevent it from caching the file, 
// you don't have to add the ? variable if you aren't worried about it     
// updating smoothly
```

Then in the "LoaderComplete" function we just get the xml out.  Hope that helps.

```
var convoXML:XML = new XML(event.target.data);
```